# Embedded SQL - Baan/LN Programming

Tags: erp, infor-ln, baan

I'm working through the loop structure information for the programming language inside of baan/ln.

The structure is generally a

```
SELECT
... a few control words and associated operations --
ENDSELECT
```

The control word in question is SELECTEOS which applies operations after the last selected record.

I'm trying to better understand the concepts, is there a history or explanation for why "EOS" was chosen as a suffix on SELECT?

Comment: It stands for "End of Search".

Answer (score 0):

suffix (EOS) = (End Of Search)